# Mailkit won't connect to gmx.com via Pop3 or Imap

Tags: email, .net-core, mailkit, email-client

I'm trying to connect to a gmx account I set up for myself, and I can't even get past the Connection phase much less the Authentication phase.

Here's the code, short and sweet:

```cs
public ConnectPopClient(string host = "pop.gmx.com", int port = 995,
                        string username = "me@gmx.com", string password = "password")
{
    using (Pop3Client pop = new Pop3Client(new ProtocolLogger("pop.log"){LogTimestamps = true}))
    {
        try
        {
            pop.Connect(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.None);
            pop.Authenticate(username.Text, password.Password);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(pop.IsConnected)
                pop.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
}
```

As should be obvious, all I wanted was for the code to connect, log in with my credentials, and disconnect without throwing any exceptions.

The log only contains the following:

> 2023-03-01T23:19:11Z Connected to pop://pop.gmx.com:995/

I can't seem to include the text of the exception, which is really well written, but it includes 6 points which I'll respond to below.

> See https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#SslHandshakeException for possible solutions.

So here are my responses to the points. (I have deleted the points which I can confirm don't apply)

> 2. The local system is missing a Root or Intermediate certificate needed to verify the server's certificate.

This seems the most likely problem, but where would I go about getting this?  I would think I'd query the server, be given the public cert and then install it.  I tried using the ServerCertificateValidationCallback but it never gets called.

> 3. A Certificate Authority CRL server for one or more of the certificates in the chain is temporarily unavailable

Possible.  Unlikely, because I get the same error with Gmail as well as GMX.
Here's what I get without SSL:

[Help Link](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog)

Exception message:

> The POP3 server has unexpectedly disconnected.

**Update:**

Using 2 other nuget packages, I have confirmed the problem is #2 or #3.  I get this exception:

> The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

I get the same errors with Gmail, so I know it's something on my system now.  Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a typo in your sample code:

```
pop.Connect(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.None);
```

but that is wrong. Port 995 is the SSL port, so using `None` won't work - that can *only* be used for plain-text connections. It tells MailKit not to use SSL at all.

What you want (if you are connecting to port 995) is:

```
pop.Connect(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
```

Based on your update, what you *may* need to do is this:

```
pop.CheckCertificationRevocation = false;
pop.Connect(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
```

If that doesn't work, then try this:

```
pop.CheckCertificationRevocation = false;
pop.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s,c,h,e) => true;
pop.Connect(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
```

If that works, then the next step would be to implement an actual ServerCertificateValidationCallback method and step through that method with a debugger to see what SslPolicyErrors you've got.

Comment: It's sort of a typo... it was leftover from when I was trying all the options in the enum and ended on it before I landed here.  What's weird is the exact same code (with SSLOnConnect) works on a colleague's machine and gives a certificate revocation error on a third, so it's clear the problem is on my machine, and maybe the one with the revocation error.  Any ideas where I should look to fix it?